# How to check with Regular Expression if user's input is valid file's extension?

Tags: python, regex

A user is expected to input a file extension, and I want to check if it's valid. If not, I want to ask to reenter it.

I'm thinking that the input should match these rules:

- It can start with dot
- All other symbols after the dot (or without it) can be just digits and letters

I tried regex like this:

```
 r'(\.)?\w+'
```

But id doesn't work for me as it matches a string that only contains alphanumeric and underscore symbols and does not require a dot at the start, and allows any characters, other than those allowed, to be typed.

Comment: Please explain just what "doesn't work for me" means.

Comment: Try `re.match(r'\.\w+$', s)` to match a string starting with a dot and then having word chars only. Note that `\w` matches letters, digits and `_`. You may subtract `_`with `[^\W_]`.

Comment: try practicing here http://regexr.com/

Comment: @Bam, please update the question to clarify the doubts of all those who voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking that the input should match these rules: it can start with dot. all other symbols after the dot (or without it) can be just digits and letters.

Note that to match an entire string with a pattern, you need to use anchors, `^` (not necessary with `re.match`) and `$`. You do not need them if you use Python 3.x `re.fullmatch`.

Next point: if you need to make `.` obligatory you need to remove the `?` quantifier after the dot pattern, as it matches 1 or 0 occurrences.

Also, to match only alphanumeric symbols, do not use `\w` since it matches underscores, too.

You may use

```
re.match(r'\.[^\W_]+$', s)
```

or (to only support ASCII letters and digits whatever the modifier/Python version is used)

```
re.match(r'\.[a-zA-Z]+$', s)
```

to check if a string starts with a dot, then has 1 or more letters or digits up to the end of string.